# What semiconductor materials are used in the 2N3904?

Tags: transistors, semiconductors

The 2N3904 type transistor is manufactured by a number of companies, using different layouts, but the characteristic requirements are the same for all of them. Do these requirements imply the usage of a particular semiconductor material? For example, simple group IV semiconductor with silicon or more complex materials such as III-V or II-VI materials? One would assume silicon-based material but I am curious if there is a source of information on this?

Thanks in advance.

Sam

Comment: They are silicon NPN transistors, nothing exotic.  It would be difficult to make a functional replacement with anything else.

Comment: Most production is done on wafers (planar processing.) The wafers are made out of very pure silicon that is pulled (multiple times) from melts in "boules." These boules are sliced into wafers. There are a number of processing steps which then take place to build the devices. Eventually, these are tested on the wafer first and those that pass are cut and packaged and, often, tested again.

Comment: (Boules might be pulled with an initial dopant already added to save a processing step. But I think this is done more for larger scale bipolar ICs rather than just for discrete parts.)

Comment: Silicon with N and P type dopants.  (the dopants would come from groups III and V)

Comment: In theory, it could be implemented in III/V materials as long as the result met the specifications. In reality, the specs are easy to meet using silicon, and silicon fabrication is *much* cheaper than other semiconductors, so using anything else would be extremely unlikely (more like "unimaginable").

Comment: In practice, different vendor's '3904's are similar enough that in the surface mount form (MMBT3904) they're used interchangably as temperature sensors. For example, some fan control chips and the [LTC2990](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/2990fe.pdf) are designed to use MMBT3904 as an external temperature sensor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This particular part uses silicon as the semiconductor. 
If in doubt, go to a manufactures website and query the material breakdown of a component. This information is required

http://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/product.do?id=2N3904#tab=tabSpecifications

which links to:

http://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/MaterialComposition.do?searchParts=2N3904

$$
\begin{array}{c|} 
 & \text{Substance}  \\ \hline
\text{Die} & Silicon\\ \hline
\text{Lead Frame} & Silver, Copper\\ \hline
\text{Mold} & Brominated\ epoxy\ resin, Phenolic\ Resin, Antimony Trioxide, fused\ Silica \\ \hline
\text{Plating} & Lead, Tin\\ \hline
\text{Wire Bond} & Gold\\ \hline
\text{Conflict Minerals} & Gold, Tin\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$